# Can i do two jpa queries in one?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, java-8

Im devloping a crud application in spring-boot and i was wondering if i can do these two queries and methods in one:

```java
package com.celulaweb.crud.repository;

import com.celulaweb.crud.domain.Cidade;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CidadeRepository extends JpaRepository<Cidade, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Cidade c where c.estado is null or c.estado = :estado")
    Page<Cidade> listarPorEstado(@Param("estado") String estado, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("select c from Cidade c where c.nome is null or c.nome like :nome")
    Page<Cidade> listarPorNomeTendo(@Param("nome") String nome, Pageable pageable);

}
```

These are queries from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`
How can i merge these two?

Comment: As you're referring to the same table 'Cidade' in both the queries, you can use the combination of 'or' and 'and' conditions in the where clause to fetch it.

Comment: Hi @Barefooter, i did this but it didnt work properly because my like stopped working

Answer (score -1):

If you have the same `Pageable` on this methods try this

```
    @Query("""
        select c from Cidade c 
        where (c.estado is null or (c.estado = :estado))
        and (c.nome is null or (c.nome like :nome))
     """
    )
    Page<Cidade> listarEntries(
        @Param("estado") estado: String,
        @Param("nome") nome: String,
        pageable: Pageable
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Максим! Thanks for your answer, but it didnt work